# Choose between android::DefaultKeyedVector<key,value> and std::map<key,value> for better performance?

Tags: android, c++, stl, c++20, android-7.0-nougat

I want to create a service in android (Nougat/Pie version) which needs to store lots of data in terms of <Key, Value> pairs. I have different APIs which update, add, delete and get the values from  <Key, Value>. Now I have two choices between

- android::DefaultKeyedVector<key,value> [https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-dev/include/utils/KeyedVector.h]
- std::map<key,value> [C++ Standard Template Library]. 
  **Can anybody help me with which one should I choose for better performance?** Has anyone done the benchmark between the two methods?

Comment: If you're going to benchmark those, I'd also throw [parralel-hashmap](https://github.com/greg7mdp/parallel-hashmap) into the mix, I've heard good things about it.

Comment: I was looking for something which is Standard, therefore I have the choice only between these two as stated in the question. @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Which standard you're referring to? `android::` stuff is not a part of C++ standard, obviously.

Comment: I mean to say that I have the choice between these two only, does anybody benchmark these two maps?